# How to install Electron app per machine without having to use admin rights for using all features?

Tags: electron, electron-builder

I need to install my Electron app for all users, but doing this makes it necessary to always start it with admin rights, because NodeJS tries to manipulate files within the program directory. I have tried to unpack the corresponding files and copy them into the userprofile, but doing so is really messy, since it breaks all the relative paths. Is there a way to automatically add a few files to user data without having to take of all the paths?

Comment: If you install app for all users means admin and another user also can access app, So in this way you must have to admin rights. might there is no way for this type of scenario

Comment: But there must be a way to move some files to user data

Comment: yes you can move files after installation but also for that you have to appropriate permission to move files in program folder.